# Google Tag Manager - collect data attributes without using the datalayer

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm trying to collect the value of data attributes when clicking on the element containing it but I would like to do it without using the datalayer.

I'm currently using the datalayer by pushing the data attribute into the datalayer with javascript, everything works but it's annoying to always modify the code, I'd like to do the same without using javascript.

My code looks like this:

```
<a href="<mylink>" class="link_class" data-shop="aaa" data-product="bbb">link label</a>
```

In Google Tag Manager, I have created an "automatic event variable" (not sure it is called like this in English, my GTM is in French) using the name "Generic_Dataset_product" where I select "element attribute" and as an attribute, I have tried multiple things without success like data-product, gtm.data-product, product, ...

To use this variable I have created a simple trigger that detects clicks on class "link_class" and associated an event (event_category, event_action, event_label) where I add the collected variables with the right name {{Generic_Dataset_product}}. Instead of seeing the expected value, I see "track_event".

Is there a way to collect data this way? I want to use the "automatic event variables" to collect content from src, data attributes, and other elements in the code as there are no predefined variables for this in GTM.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to avoid the datalayer. The datalayer already contains the clicked element, and the data attributes are properties of that element, so you can address them via dot notation like this:

[image: datalayer variable for data attribute]

This saves you custom javascript (which is something you might want to avoid if you ever plan to implement a proper content security policy, since custom scripts require the use of eval).

Comment: That's what I'm currently using but I have to push the data attributes withJS and that's what I would like to avoid. I would like to manage everything in GTM to avoid maintaining fragments of code everywhere. Is there a way to feed the datalayer automatically with all attributes?

Comment: I do not understand the comment. With the solution above, you do not need to push anything with javascript. The gtm.element variable with all it's properties is automatically pushed to the datalayer when you have a click trigger, the only thing you need to do is to enable the built-in click element variable. Then it will pick up the data attributes without any additional script.

Comment: Ok, I thought I had to push it from JS first but yes indeed, I have tried this out and for some reason, it was initially not working but now it is. I suppose I did something wrong somewhere else. Thanks!

Comment: @EikePierstorff TGM documentation shows we can get a list of all the variables, but not their values.

Is there a way to get all the values of each var?

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/reference#Variables

Answer (score 4):

Getting arbitrary attributes of clicked elements in GTM is a trivial task. And there are many ways of doing it. I prefer CJS cuz I often need to do mutations and sanitizing there. Your problem is that you're not debugging it properly.

First, make a trivial CJS variable like so:

```js
function(){
  return {{Click Element}}.getAttribute("data-shop");
}
```

Now open your preview debugger and actually go inspect all variables GTM sets **on your click**. Including your new CJS var as well as your auto-event vars. If you don't find what you're looking for from there, come back here and show us screenshots from the actual debugger and let's debug from there.

Here's how you enable {{Click Element}}: [image]

Comment: Thanks! I may be missing the obvious but in order to use you CJS example, I need some way of triggering it. Do I first need to create an automatic variable called {{Clicked Element}} ? If yes, what variable type would that be?

Comment: It's a default variable, but you may need to enable it if you haven't yet. Attached the screenshot to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I understand why it was not working. The name of the variable is {{Click Element}} instead of {{Clicked Element]], it was just a typo, that's why it couldn't replicate your solution, thanks :)

Comment: @BNazaruk TGM documentation shows we can get a list of all the variables, but not their values.

Is there a way to get all the values of each var?

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/reference#Variables

Comment: That's the API. GTM's API essentially lets you get registered variables. It has no access to runtime values. Simo at one point went through how to get the variables at the runtime from the global scope here with the .macro() method: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/mysterious-macro-call-custom-html-tags/ But I'm not sure that it's still there as a method and even when it was there, it was not useful since it didn't map the values to var names.