# Why is my Custom Javascript variable on Google Tag Manager returning "Null"

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am having issues getting a response with my custom variable. if I return {{Click Element}}.class - I'm able to retrieve the class name. But soon as I attempt to get the data attribute I get "null" or "undefined" What am I doing wrong?

Also just to note, there are similar questions regarding this,([Google Tag Manager - collect data attributes without using the datalayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70144690/google-tag-manager-collect-data-attributes-without-using-the-datalayer)) but their answers doesn't solve this one.

[image]

[image]

I've attempted to  create variables and referring the attribute to the variable.
getAttributeName()

Comment: First. You need to make sure the `click element` is what you expected. Usually GTM will detect the `click element` is the parent or the child of the element you want. You can add some screenshots about the `click element` and the `trigger` you used.

Comment: @darrelltw many thanks for the response. I've found the issue which you have also mentioned. I needed the click event to retrieve the data from the parent.

Comment: It's quite like this question. You can check some refer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73401415/gtm-click-element-trigger-isnt-firing/73405179#73405179